# How to place nodes on a Tikz plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, tikz-node

I have this curve made with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [cyan,line width=1mm] plot [smooth, tension=2] coordinates { (0,0) (5,3) (9,-1) (11,4)} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to place several nodes on this plot. I know this is somehow possible within the `axis` environment but I have no idea how to do it here.

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128579/82917

Comment: The non-accepted answer of @campa's link is relevant as well as it explains the background of how “nodes along a path” works internally. It requires a “timer”. The `plot` operation doesn't provide one. You either have to use [PGFPlots](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-annotations#sec-28.3), the `decoration.markings` library or the `spath3` library which basically does the same as `decoration.markings`.

Comment: Here's the a section of [tikz manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.8) related to placing nodes on a curve. Since you are using `plot`, you may need another approach. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172842/how-to-label-the-curve-of-a-function-at-any-point-along-it-in-tikz).

Comment: Another word: the normal TikZ timer doesn't place nodes linear to the length of a curve linear to the time (hence the name). That's the *t* variable in the function for a [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). The `decoration.markings` library does work differently as even unitless values are considered fractions of the total length of the decorated path. If you want something timer like for the individual curves that the PGF plot handlers generate, we will have to dig into the internals. `spath3` could help here maybe.

Comment: I found the answer on the Tikz manual, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So I went to the TikZ manual as suggested by @Celdor and I did the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [cyan,line width=1mm] (0,0) .. controls (3,5) and (6,-1) .. (7,2)  node (a1) [pos=0.1,circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,fill]{} node (a2) [pos=0.3,circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,fill]{} node (a3) [pos=0.8,circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,fill]{}  ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following:
[image]

Thanks!