# TikZ: add blur and shade on a curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-blur, tikz-shadings

I have the following curve from a [previous thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700222/how-to-place-nodes-on-a-tikz-plot?noredirect=1#comment1740756_700222):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [cyan,line width=1mm] (0,0) .. controls (3,5) and (6,-1) .. (7,2)    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to add 2 effects (separately):

1. I would like to "blur" the curve (i.e., to convolve the image with a 2-D Gaussian kernel).
2. I would like to add some shading. More precisely I would like the colour of the curve to progressively become white (or preferably transparent, but white will do) in some areas.

I would some documentation for the [shading library](https://tikz.dev/library-shadings) but nothing for curves (only areas).

Many thanks in advance

Comment: One idea for the shading would be to trasform your curve into an area.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244650/glowing-path-in-tikz help?

Comment: @cfr do you meen the loop to plot multiple curves with different width and shades of black? I love it! I will implement it and update the thread.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134283/tikz-shading-a-path-without-any-filling help? EDIT: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337898/how-do-i-use-spath3-package-to-shading-a-path probably better. EDIT EDIT: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566963/tikz-shading-a-path-fade-no-fill-sty-does-not-work-as-previously-oct-2020/567029#567029 is the most recent?

Answer (score 2):

Using `fade-no-fill.sty` from [Hotschke and Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567029/) for the shading and [percusse's method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244966/) for blurring, a shaded and blurred path can be drawn.

[image: shaded and blurred cyan-magenta path]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700367/
% fade-no-fill o:
% ateb Hotschke updated gan Andrew Stacey: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567029/
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327713/86}
\usepackage{fade-no-fill}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xc using 0.5*100*ln(10/\x)] in {10,9.9,...,1}{
    \path [fade path but don't fill={line width=\x*1pt,transparent!0}{left color=cyan!\xc,right color=magenta!\xc}] (0,0) .. controls (3,5) and (6,-1) .. (7,2)    ;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that you would not want to use this too often as it is s-l-l-o-o-o-w.

## Edit

The code works OK for me in Beamer, too.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700367/
% fade-no-fill o:
% ateb Hotschke updated gan Andrew Stacey: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567029/
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327713/86}
\usepackage{fade-no-fill}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xc using 0.5*100*ln(10/\x)] in {10,9.9,...,1}{
      \path [fade path but don't fill={line width=\x*1pt,transparent!0}{left color=cyan!\xc,right color=magenta!\xc}] (0,0) .. controls (3,5) and (6,-1) .. (7,2)    ;
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: curve shown in Beamer slide]

Note that I'm using the *second* version of the `sty` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567029/ i.e. the updated one added in July 2021 by Andrew Stacey, modified in light of changes to `spath3`.

Comment: Or if you do want to use many, you may be interested in `memoize` ... ;).

Comment: Thanks @cfr. I created a modified version of `fade-no-fill.sty` file but using `spath3` as `spath` is depreciated, using https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337898/how-do-i-use-spath3-package-to-shading-a-path but unfortunately I get a lot of errors when compiling

Comment: I worked it out on a standalone document, but for some reason it produces a blank image in my Beamer document

Comment: @Andros I used the `sty` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567029/. The second one in that answer - not the first. That uses `spath3` and was updated in July 2021.

Comment: @Andros I've added the code and output for my Beamer test. See edit above.

Answer (score 1):

So I have implemented that solution from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244650/glowing-path-in-tikz)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x[evaluate={\xc=0.5*100*ln(10/\x);}] in {10,9.9,...,1}{
        \draw [draw=cyan!\xc,line width=\x*1pt] (0,0) .. controls (3,5) and (6,-1) .. (7,2)    ;
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produce this acceptable output.
[image: blurred curve]
However I don't understand why using `cyan!\xc` instead of `draw=cyan!\xc` returns

```
Package color Error: Argument `1.02026' not in range [0,1]. ^^I}
```

as `\xc` is supposed to be between 0 and 100...

I still have no solution for shading the curve...

Comment: I think it is trying to interpret the colour using a different colour model. *Why* it is doing that I'm not sure.